# Difference between Run and Exploit

Tags: exploit, metasploit

When using Metasploit for running exploits you have two options:

```
run
exploit
```

what is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no differences, as `exploit` is an alias to `run`:

```
Auxiliary Commands
==================

    Command       Description
    -------       -----------
    check         Check to see if a target is vulnerable
    exploit       This is an alias for the run command
    pry           Open a Pry session on the current module
    rcheck        Reloads the module and checks if the target is vulnerable
    recheck       This is an alias for the rcheck command
    reload        Reloads the auxiliary module
    rerun         Reloads and launches the auxiliary module
    rexploit      This is an alias for the rerun command
    run           Launches the auxiliary module
```

... and:

```
> help exploit
Usage: run [options]

Launches an auxiliary module.
...
```

like:
    *`rexploit` is an alias for the `rerun` command*.